# Browsing JSON variable in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

For some reasons, I'm not allowed to use `jsqon_query` with Ansible, I'm trying to reach `stdout` element in a `results` list in a variable resulting from a `shell` call.

The JSON variable is saved this way :

```
"request": {
    "changed": true, 
    "msg": "All items completed", 
    "results": [
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null, 
            "_ansible_item_result": true, 
            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
            "_ansible_parsed": true, 
            "changed": true, 
            "cmd": "echo \"****:********\" | grep -o -P '^*****:[^\\n]*$' | awk '{split($0,a,\":\"); print a[2]}'", 
            "delta": "0:00:00.003660", 
            "end": "2018-10-31 17:26:17.697864", 
            "failed": false, 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "echo \"**************\" | grep -o -P '^************:[^\\n]*$' | awk '{split($0,a,\":\"); print a[2]}'", 
                    "_uses_shell": true, 
                    "chdir": null, 
                    "creates": null, 
                    "executable": null, 
                    "removes": null, 
                    "stdin": null, 
                    "warn": true
                }
            }, 
            "item": "**********:************", 
            "rc": 0, 
            "start": "2018-10-31 17:26:17.694204", 
            "stderr": "", 
            "stderr_lines": [], 
            "stdout": "**********", 
            "stdout_lines": [
                "*********"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I'm trying to browse my `stdout` element this way :

```
- name: Tarball copy
  copy: src= "{{ '%s/%s' | format( TARBALL_DIR , request.results[0].stdout ) }}" dest= "/tmp/tarball/"
```

I tryied also :

```
- name: Tarball copy
  copy: src= "{{ '%s/%s' | format( TARBALL_DIR , request.results[.stdout] ) }}" dest= "/tmp/tarball/"

- name: Tarball copy
  copy: src= "{{ '%s/%s' | format( TARBALL_DIR , item.stdout ) }}" dest= "/tmp/tarball/"
  with_items: "{{ request.results }}"
```

I've no idea why I'm always getting the same error : 
- template error while templating string: unexpected '.'. String: {{ request.results[.stdout] }} *(when trying with [.stdout)*
- The task includes an option with an undefined variable *(when putting [0] index)*

Comment: The first one looks like it should work, except that you need to single quote TARBALL_DIR like so: `'TARBALL_DIR'`.

Comment: Even if ```TARBALL_DIR``` is a host var ?

Comment: No, not if that is a variable. Can you post the error you get from that?

Comment: That was the following one : 
```- template error while templating string: unexpected '.'. String: {{ request.results[.stdout] }}```

Comment: That's the second one.  What was the output from ` request.results[0].stdout `?

Comment: Sorry yes, I meant the second message `- The task includes an option with an undefined variable`

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved my problem using :

```
- name: Tarball copy
  copy: 
    src: "{{ '%s/%s' | format( TARBALL_DIR , request.results[0].stdout ) }}" 
    dest: "/tmp/tarball/"
```

It seems that src and dest couldn't accept space after the equal char.